# How to decode this URL on iOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, decode

`%E8%BF%99%E4%B8%AA%E5%B8%A6%E4%B8%8D%E5%B8%A6%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87.doc`

This is a parameter from server . How to decode it on iOS development by Objective-C ?

Comment: This string is a kind of NSString in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
NSString *url = [@"%E8%BF%99%E4%B8%AA%E5%B8%A6%E4%B8%8D%E5%B8%A6%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87.doc" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thank you!     After that, I tried doing this below.

Comment: [title stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: That's okay to solve this problem. Before I tried to do this below. `- (nullable NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;`    But it doesn't work, so I also try to do another method.  That is: `- (nullable NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;`   Finally , it  works !  Thank you!

Comment: Could I ask does these two methods can support the minimum of iOS version 7.0?       `NS_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_11, 2_0, 9_0, "Use -stringByRemovingPercentEncoding instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding.");`

Comment: mostly use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Okay, I got it. it was firstly deprecated in iOS 9.0, after that version , us `-stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` instead.THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

To decode the parameters which is getting from server...

Try this :

make property in `.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *str;
```

and then store your response in this string like :

in your `.m` file:

```
_str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope this is helpful to you.. :)

Comment: You're right! That is an another solution for decoding string.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!  I solved it by this below: `- (nullable NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;`

Comment: Ok... great..all the best